# Top command redirection

Tags: shell

I am trying to analyse a randomly crashing application.To get some details of the process i am implementing a script like below

```
procID=$(ps -aef|grep app|awk '{print $2}')

top -p $procID -b -d 10 > test.log
```

In this case top command will execute for every 10 sec and write to `test.log`. Planning to run it indefinitely, but I want to flush out the contents of `test.log` each time top command writes some value to it. How can I modify the script accordingly ?

Comment: flush out, what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean clear the contents of test.log each time.I don't want the contents of test.log to grow so big.

Comment: why not using `logrotate` to avoid your test file to grow ? Because if you override each time, your log will just be a reflect to the result of the top command...

Comment: How do i use it?

Comment: have you seen my answer ? Did it work ?

Comment: Thanks Derlin.It did not work.There might be a possibility that i am doing something wrong.One quick question though.My log name is test.log so i created a file named test and updated the configuration whatever you have given. i get error like this                                                                           sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/test
error: /etc/logrotate.d/test:3 bad size '4M  # rotate after 1'
error: found error in /var/log/test.log , skipping

Comment: remove the comments in the file, i.e. everything starting with `#`

Comment: is it better without comments ?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid your log getting too big, I suggest you use [`logrotate`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) instead. In short, `logrotate` creates a cronjob that will "rotate" your log file upon a condition (one file per day, rotate when the file reaches a given size, etc.). You can also choose to keep the X last rotated logs.

This is what is used for `lastmessage` and the other linux log files (hence the `.log.1`, `.log.2` etc.)

**Here is a basic way to make it work:**

Create a configuration for your file in `/etc/logrotate.d`. For example:

```
# /etc/logrotate.d/test
/var/log/test.log {
    size 4M 
    create 770 somegroup someuser
    rotate 4 
    missingok 
    copytruncate
}
```

What it says:

- `size 4M`: rotate file after it reaches 4M in size
- `create ...`: create new file with the given permisions (replace `somegroup someuser` by your usergroup and username)
- `rotate 4`: keep the last 4 log files (`test.log`, `test.log.1` etc)
- `missingOk` an `copyTruncate`: avoid some errors (see the doc for more info)

Check that your file is correct by executing:

```
sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/test
```

enjoy.

More about logrotate: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/understanding-logrotate-utility/